# Unable to Retrieve NR CellSignalStrength on 5G NSA Mode Using Telephony in OnePlus 8T 5G

Tags: android, kotlin, telephony, 5g

I'm trying to obtain the CellSignalStrength for a device operating in 5G NSA mode. Specifically, I want to retrieve both LTE and NR signal strengths since 5G NSA mode should involve both. However, I'm facing an inconsistency between different devices:

- On the OPPO A78 5G (ColorOS, Android 13), I'm able to retrieve both LTE and NR signal strengths as expected.
- On the OnePlus 8T 5G (OxygenOS, Android 13), I only get CellSignalStrengthLTE, even though the device is in 5G NSA mode (100% checked).

I'm puzzled because some apps on the Play Store are able to capture NR signal strengths on the OnePlus 8T 5G.

*FYI : Everything works well on both device when 5G SA mode turn on

How can I accurately retrieve ss-rsrp and ss-rsrq values from the 5G NSA mode on the OnePlus 8T 5G?

I'm using the Telephony framework to fetch the CellSignalStrength. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
fun requestCellInfoUpdate() {
        //Get the system's TelephonyManager service.
        mTelephonyManager = context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
        
        //Ceate a TelephonyManager instance for the default subscription ID. (Current Data SIM)
        mTelephonyManager = mTelephonyManager.createForSubscriptionId(getDefault_SubscriptionId(context))
        
        //Request cell info update (Andriod Q). The result will be handled by the provided callback.
        mTelephonyManager.requestCellInfoUpdate(context.mainExecutor, object : TelephonyManager.CellInfoCallback() {
            
            override fun onCellInfo(cellInfo: MutableList<CellInfo>) {
                // Find the currently registered cell from the list.
                val servingCell = cellInfo.find {  it.isRegistered}
                
                // If a registered cell is found for serving cellualar, update the cachedCellInfo list.
                if (servingCell != null) {
                    cachedCellInfo = listOf(servingCell)
                }
            }

            //Callback method when there's an error retrieving cell info.
            override fun onError(errorCode: Int, detail: Throwable?) {
                super.onError(errorCode, detail)
                // Handle the error as needed. For example, log the error or display an error message.
            }
        })
    }

fun getInfo(): List<String> {

        //Request the current cell information.
        requestCellInfoUpdate() // Update Cell Information on return to `cachedCellInfo`

        var cellId: String
        var cellSignalStrength: String
        var telephonyList: List<String> = emptyList()

        //Check if the cached cell information is available.
        if (cachedCellInfo.isEmpty()) {
            // If not available, set error messages indicating the GPS needs to be on.
            cellId = "Error! GPS must be turned on."
            cellSignalStrength = "Error! GPS must be turned on."
        } else {
            //Extract cell identity and signal strength from the cached information.

            cellId = cachedCellInfo[0].cellIdentity.toString() // index 0 to get only Serving Cell data
            cellSignalStrength = cachedCellInfo[0].cellSignalStrength.toString() // index 0 to get only Serving Cell data

        }
        
        //Add the extracted cell identity and signal strength to the result list.
        telephonyList += cellId // index [i]
        telephonyList += cellSignalStrength // index [i+1]
    
        return telephonyList
    }
```

Given that the device is in 5G NSA mode, I was expecting to get signal strengths for both LTE and NR. However, as mentioned, on the OnePlus 8T 5G, I only receive the LTE signal strength.

I initially thought it might be a hardware limitation, but since other apps can capture the NR signal strength on this specific device, I believe there's a way to achieve this.

Any guidance on how to accurately capture the ss-rsrp and ss-rsrq values for 5G NSA mode would be greatly appreciated.